# async await code not running in right order in Blazor WebAssembly app

Tags: async-await, blazor, blazor-webassembly

This is easiest to explain by showing the code first.
1st snippet of code is inside a component i'm calling a function in another class (IsAuthenticated), it has await before it:

```
    bool ret = await AppState.IsAuthenticated(false);
    Console.WriteLine($"3) MainLayout OnInitializedAsync() ret={ret}, AppState.ActiveUserIsImpersonated = {AppState.ActiveUserIsImpersonated}");
```

2nd snippet of code is the IsAuthenticated function (which is async):

```
        public async Task<bool> IsAuthenticated(bool redirectToLoginIfNot)
    {
        if (_authenticatedUser != null)
            return true;
        string authToken = await GetBasicAuthToken();
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(authToken) && ActiveUser == null)
            _authenticatedUser = await ApiGetAuthenticatedUser(true);
        if (ActiveUser == null && redirectToLoginIfNot)
            _navigationManager.NavigateTo("/login");
        int? impersonatedUserId = await GetImpersonatedUserId();

        Console.WriteLine($"1) AppState IsAuthenticated()  impersonatedUserId={impersonatedUserId}");

        if (impersonatedUserId.HasValue)
            _impersonatedUser = await ApiGetUser(impersonatedUserId.Value, true);

        Console.WriteLine($"2) AppState IsAuthenticated()  _impersonatedUser?.UserID={_impersonatedUser?.UserID}");

        return _authenticatedUser != null;
    }
```

Only thing that matters really is the 3 Console.WriteLine lines that contain 1) 2) and 3).
I'd expect it to run in that order: 1,2 & 3, but sometimes it doesn't, see this console output:

[image]

Im confused, how come 3 is running before 2, 2 is within the IsAuthenticated() function and 3) is in the outer function that calls IsAuthenticated() AFTER the call to the function.
I have await there, so why  doesnt it wait for IsUthenticated() to complete before carrying on running code in the outer function?

Comment: `OnInitializedAsync` will (asynchronously) wait for `IsAuthenticated` to complete. I'd check for other calls to `IsAuthenticated`. If you can't find any, then please post a minimal repro.

Comment: It's based on how the "component" async method works. ```OnInitializedAsync```, for instance, continues the render cycle when hitting the first await (not even waiting for the result). So, the next child component, ```OnInitializedAsync``` is executed and so on. If you could provide more code of your component, it should be easier to explain it in more detail.